# Partial ordering with only reflexive relation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I have a problem understanding orders.
For know, how i understand partial order is: pair of set and relation that orders it.
From that pair, let's say, we can create some kind or 'ordered list'.
For example, let's say that we have set $A=\{5, 3, 1, 2\}$ and relation $R=\{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 5)\}$, so we can, on this basis create 'ordered list' like: $$L = [1, 2, 3, 5]$$ because we are able to compare all elements with each other.
But let's try to consider partial order $R = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 5)\}$ which is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric, so it fulfills all properties needed to be named partial order. How do I proceed with such relation? How do I create such 'ordered list'? Or is there something not ok with my understanding of orders?

Comment: From $R$ you can create exactly $4$ ordered lists. Each of them contains just one element. In your notation the lists are $[1]$, $[2]$, $[3]$, and $[5]$. You were able to create a single list from $R$ because $R$ is not just a partial order: it’s a linear order, also called a total order.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. So you say, that partial order can create many lists? Not one that contains all elements, where their order is defined by relation? And if it can create many lists, these lists can contain only elements that are comparable within this relation?

Comment: *List* isn’t a standard term here; I was using it in the way that I thought (on the basis of your example) that you probably intended it, to mean what is usually called a chain in the partial order, i.e., a subset that is linearly ordered by the partial order, meaning that all of the members of the chain are comparable.

Comment: Yes, i know, but i don't know the way to properly write it as i intended, and i wanted to write ordered set, that's why i used list as an example what was in my mind. Sorry about that. So, to have it clear. If we have a set, and relation that is partial order, we can only create ordered sets from elements, that are comparable within that relation, and if we can't compare them, we don't include them? Is this a correct way to understand it?

Comment: Yes, if you want a totally ordered subset, you must use elements that are comparable in the partial order.

Comment: I can't give you upvote because of my weak reputation, but i want you to know, that i appreciate that very much. Thanks.

Comment: You’re very welcome; I’m happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of partially ordered set does **not** guarantee that all of its elements are comparable, so you can only order certain subsets(one element subsets in your case).
If all elements of a partially ordered set are comparable you have a total order and the set is called **totally ordered** [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order)